# Massively increased new TCP connections # in .NET 4.5 over 4.0?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, tcp, .net-4.5

I am currently testing my WPF/WCF client application in .NET 4.5 vs 4.0 with a view of finally getting 4.5 rolled out to all client machines.  The WCF portion uses BasicHttpBinding/SOAP.

When testing the two client versions under the same conditions (Win7 etc), we're seeing a 10x increase in "New TCP connections" to the SOAP server endpoint - 4.0 clients establish ~450 per hour whilst 4.5 clients are establishing ~6,000.  Since we're connecting to a remote server, this is troublesome as establishing a new TCP connection adds a large latency to the web service call.

When using 4.0, We previously have tuned the client `ServicePointManager` settings to maximise our TCP connection reuse and expected these settings to be applicable to 4.5.

My application generally performs one call at a time, perhaps every 10 seconds on average - with bursts of 10 concurrent calls every few minutes.

I've had a look at the changelogs and cannot find any reference to fixes/changes that have been made to this part of .NET.  Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on here?

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;

Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settings.SendTimeout),
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settings.SendTimeout),
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
    MaxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100,
    Security =
        {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
            Message = { ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName },
            Transport = { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic },
        },
};
```

Comment: Perhaps your issue is related to this? - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826 The issue could be to do with the way threads are being assigned to handle client requests.

Comment: @Xefan Interesting point, but that link refers to server side issues, rather than the point above which is related to client connections (the server is not WCF and has not changed).

Comment: Is the server sending a chunked response by chance?  There is a known issue where chunked responses can result in the connection getting closed instead of reused.

Comment: @JonCole Is this a known issue with .Net 4.5 i.e. would it not have been seen with a .Net 4.0 client?

Comment: @JonCole We have established that the service is sending Transfer-Encoding: chunked with no Content-Length header specified.  We are investigating why they have chunked encoding enabled but in the meantime, would this be the cause of the behaviour difference we are seeing between .NET 4.0 and 4.5?  The service is also sending their responses using gzip encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed with these hotfixes:

Win7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846044
Win8: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846046

We verified the Win7 patch as working.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a regression that was introduced when fixing a different problem.  It is related to chunked Transfer-Encoding responses from the server.

For those using HttpWebRequest directly, you can workaround this issue by ensuring that your application reads the entire response stream.  This means that you need to call the Read or BeginRead method on the stream until it returns 0 as the number of bytes read.

For those using a wrapping technology like WCF, there is no known workaround on the client side.  If you have access to the server, you can change your server to send a content-length based response instead of a chunked response, which should allow you to avoid the problematic code paths on the 
client.

A fix for this issue has been identified and will be released widely in an upcoming update to the framework.  If this is blocking you, please reach out to Microsoft customer support.

Comment: Thanks @JonCole.  We await the framework update and will install a reverse proxy to counteract the 3-way handshake latency issue (among other benefits we would gain from this).

Comment: @jamespconnor If this is blocking you, you can contact Microsoft Support for KB2846046.

Comment: Hi @Varun, I can't find details of that KB anywhere online except for a brief mention of a Win8 Hotfix? is KB2846046 a fix of some sort for this issue?  We are using Win7 on our workstations.

Comment: Found it now - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846046 but looks to be applicable to Windows 8 only?